# how to fix the locale when input gitlab-ctl reconfigure

Tags: gitlab, locale

When I input `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`, it shows:

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure it shows DETAIL:  
The database was initialized with LC_COLLATE "zh_CN.UTF-8",  
which is not recognized by setlocale().
```

The system is centos7: how can I fix the problem?

The content of .bashrc

```
# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

and the content of profile

```
unset i
unset -f pathmunge
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib64
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el7_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java
export JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JRE_HOME/lib:$CLASSPATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/maven3
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

I also tried to install postgresql, when I login, it shows below.

```
[root@0c-5b-8f-27-9a-64 ~]# su - postgres
Last login: Tue Jun 22 14:30:01 CST 2021 on pts/0
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (zh_CN.UTF-8): Permission denied
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (zh_CN.UTF-8)
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (zh_CN.UTF-8)
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `en_US.UTF-8': not a valid identifier
/bin/sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (zh_CN.UTF-8)
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (zh_CN.UTF-8)
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `en_US.UTF-8': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: Would this help? https://gitmemory.com/issue/docksal/docksal/692/486088010. Or https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?23342-Trouble-locale-Settings-!!

Answer (score 2):

Check if, as in [this thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-suddenly-not-restarting-postgres-locale-problem/5204/3), you can regenerate the right locale

In your case, as [in here](https://serverfault.com/questions/275403/how-do-i-change-my-locale-to-utf-8-in-centos):

```
localedef -i zh_CN -c -f UTF-8 zh_CN.UTF-8
export LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

And change `/etc/locale.conf` to:

```
LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=zh_CN.UTF-8
```

See if the issue persists then.

Comment: I tried the three line command, but the issue still persists.

Comment: When I run `gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create`, it also shows the same problem. Is there any other way I can backup my gitlab data?

Comment: @ylliu Not really, beside opening a ticket in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/. Did you try first to modify `/etc/locale.conf`? (I have edited my answer to add that step)

Comment: It still doesn't work. And there is also a strange problem. When I login in. It shows `-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier` and `-bash: export: `en_US.UTF-8': not a valid identifier`. I have already set etc/locale.conf to zh_CN.UTF-8, but when I relogin, it changed to en_US.UTF-8. I have to reset etc/locale.conf and I also need to set LC_ALL=zh_CN.utf-8. I also tried to set /etc/locale `LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8`, but it still not work.

Comment: Could you edit your question with the content of your home .bashrc and .profile?

Comment: I've updated the question with content of .barhrc and profile. I removed some content of profile, because it said there were too much code. Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: @ylliu I don't see a line with `en_US.UTF-8`, which would trigger the error message you mention. Is it in `/etc/bashrc`?

Comment: I have no idea about it, I also tried to install postgresql, when I login, it shows something wrong which I updated in the question.

Comment: @ylliu YEs: I found two threads with commands which could possibly remedy the error message you have.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it immediately.

Comment: My system is centos 7, it seems that it doesn't support `locale-gen` command.

Comment: @ylliu Then maybe https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-set-up-system-locale-on-centos-7/ can help.